# This app is blocked error in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Our chrome extension app allows the user to connect to Gmail with OAuth2, we are currently doing a major change to the app and **the old version was working fine** (now we created a new client id and a new product in the developer dashboard for a beta testing)

the OAuth2 is working fine when the gamil account is in the related workspace but the personal emails are throwing this error (the old application is working fine)

I looked into this and it seems it is related to the client id we are using in the `manifest.xml`
following this link: [https://help.dragapp.com/en/article/how-do-i-fix-the-this-app-is-blocked-error-message-1xxo9nb/#:~:text=In%20this%20case%2C%20all%20you,your%20list%20of%20trusted%20apps](https://help.dragapp.com/en/article/how-do-i-fix-the-this-app-is-blocked-error-message-1xxo9nb/#:%7E:text=In%20this%20case%2C%20all%20you,your%20list%20of%20trusted%20apps).

is this the right way to fix it? as i currently don't have access to the https://admin.google.com

or should I submit the app for review again in the `OAuth consent screen` and specify the new client id in https://console.cloud.google.com/

can anyone guide me through this please?

[image]